# ActionBar menu on bottom bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-menu

How can I get the menu icon to appear on the bottom bar? 
It seems too wasteful to have a full bar, empty, just for the menu icon.
My target is Jelly Bean, I am not using Sherlock.

[image]

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setText("TAB LEFT");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setText("TAB RIGHT");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @Android-Developer As I said, I need the area taken by the empty bar on top. The target devices are just a few inches wide and tall, so it is a luxury I cannot afford.

Comment: To remove the `ActionBar` which appears after the tabs, you should not inflate menu to your activity. But there is no way to remove `ActionBar`, use it's tabs and put the overflow menu icon in bottom system bar.

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest you have to set the targetSdkVersion to 13 or earlier like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

The overflow menu then moves to the bottom since Android tries to be version compatible

Comment: Setting `android:targetSdkVersion="13"` will still not move the menu button on bottom system bar. You have to use `android:targetSdkVersion="10"` for that. Already tested : )

Comment: @Android-Developer I tried both suggestions, and I still get the same result as before. I will add the manifest to the question.

Comment: You could adding an entry for your  activity in the manifest as `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`
Also Your item that inflates your overflow menu should have `mustshowAsAction="always"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this entry under the "application" tag in your manifest:

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).